# Problem resolving own hostname

Tags: 10.04

I'm running 10.04 LTS server. I am unable to resolve this issue: "unable to resolve host serverubuntu".

I've attempted all of the recommended solutions and none have worked. I've read that this issue might arise from incorrect settings in the hosts and hostname files:

Here are the contests of these files:

File: hostname

```
serverubuntu
```

File: hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       serverubuntu

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Note: I've tried several different entries for the second line of the hosts file:

```
127.0.1.1  serverubuntu  serverubuntu.hvc.rr.com
127.0.1.1  serverubuntu  serverubuntu.hvc.rr.com serverubuntu
```

None have worked.

I do have my server assigned a static IP address: 192.168.1.199

Comment: When exactly do you get the "unable to resolve host serverubuntu" message?

Answer (score 0):

Your /etc/hosts file should read

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       serverubuntu//change this to 127.0.0.1
192.168.1.199   serverubuntu//add your static IP


# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```